# About domains of trigonometric functions (eg, $\sin x$ vs $\frac1{\csc x}$)

Tags: functions, trigonometry

I recently learnt that the domains of $\sin x$ and $\dfrac1{\csc x}$ are not same. Does this mean that I cannot transform one into another during trigonometric manipulations? Now, the domain of $\csc x$ and $1/\sin x$ are equal.

I can't wrap my head around this idea. I understand the maths (trigonometric functions, etc) of it all, but I want to know the idea that this conveys (a sort of a deeper meaning).

Comment: $\sin x$ is defined for $x=0$ while $1/\csc x$ is not defined for $x=0$

Comment: You CAN transform one into the other, and that will be valid in their common domain.

Comment: You're right, they are not the same. However, what is nice about the cosecant function is that it is *meromorphic*, which means its only singularities are *poles*. The reciprocal of a meromorphic function can be analytically continued such that there are zeros where the original function had poles.